# Bootstrap .container-sm class has different margin in page with vertical scrollbar and with no vertical scrollbar

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, scrollbar, bootstrap-5

I have two pages, one page content are little longer than the other. So, in one page there is vertcal scrollbar at side and other page has did not.
I am using Bootstrap class .container-sm in both the pages and there structure are also almost same. But the problem is one has different margin then the other without scrollbar which creates uneven design. How to fix this thing?

Thank you

Here is the general structure for both the pages.

```
<div class="container-sm">
  <!-- Navbar-Section -->
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light pt-5">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!-- Navbar here -->
    </div>
  </nav>
  <!-- Main Heading & Subheading -->
  <div class="container-fluid py-4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-md-6 py-2 py-sm-5 pe-lg-5">
          
        </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Here is the margin image of the page with the scrollbar and without scrollbar.[page with scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QG2ad.png)
[page without scrollbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eg2ca.png)

Comment: Can you provide both code instead of general code so it would be easy for us to identify the problem.